# sqlj runtime error

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, sqlj

Could somebody tell me what is causing this error when using sqlj in Oracle 11g. I am using Solaris 8 and I have tried changing JDK versions (tried both 1.5 and 1.6).

```
bash-2.03$ ~/11.2.0.2/bin/sqlj -compile=false -classpath '~/11.2.0.2/sqlj/lib/translator.jar:~/11.2.0.2/sqlj/lib/runtime12.jar'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sqlj/runtime/profile/DefaultLoader
at sqlj.tools.Sqlj.resetStaticVariables(Sqlj.java:2905)
at sqlj.tools.Sqlj.statusMain(Sqlj.java:189)
at sqlj.tools.Sqlj.main(Sqlj.java:150)
```

The same command works fine with Oracle 10g:

```
bash-2.03$ ~/10.2.0.3/bin/sqlj -compile=false -classpath '~/10.2.0.3/sqlj/lib/translator.jar::~/10.2.0.3/sqlj/lib/runtime12.jar'
Error: This SQLJ runtime must be run under an Oracle JDBC driver.
```

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: How did you get sqlj working? I receive complaints about not using proper version of JDK. It's stupid..

Comment: Hi, Were you able to resolve it? If not, try setting the ORACLE_HOME and JAVA_HOME to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.oracle/oc4j/11/jars/runtime12.jar.html) the `runtime12.jar` should contain this class - so the question is - did you try running `ls ~/11.2.0.2/sqlj/lib/runtime12.jar` to verify the path exists?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the path exists. The problem was due to wrong JDK version. It worked fine after I set the ORACLE_HOME and JAVA_HOME to the proper values (used JDK 1.5 to make it work).